# I'm creating a canvas drawing apps but stuck

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a canvas drawing apps but I got stuck in my code. I am new to javascript so it seems difficult for me:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('chColor');

input.onkeyup = function() {
 document.getElementById('color_check').style.background = input.value;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',painting,false);


function painting() {
 
 
 canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
 var mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
 var mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

 ctx.fillStyle = input.value;
 ctx.fillRect(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);
 }

 canvas.onmouseup = function() {
  canvas.onmousemove = '';
 }
 
}

var erase = document.getElementById('clear');

erase.onclick = function() {
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

```css
body {
 background: #dfdfdf;
}
.colorplate {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#chColor {
 width: 250px;
 border:none;
 background: none;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
#chColor:focus {
 outline: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#333;
}

#color_check {
 position: absolute;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 top:0;
 left:50%;
}
canvas {
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#clear {
 padding: 10px;
 border:none;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 cursor: pointer;
}
#clear:hover {
 background: #333;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorplate">
  <input type="text" id="chColor" placeholder="type your color name or hex">
  <div id="color_check"></div>
 </div>bbb
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="clear">Erase all</button>
```

> please update some code and make to much beautiful than mine. I hope you will help me  for my problem.

Comment: you want to make this code beautiful ?

Comment: no! I want you to make this apps good than mine

Comment: Please read this to understand how to raise your chances of getting an answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking Currently it is not clear what is the problem you're asking people to solve

Comment: If it is working you could post it on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks @PhilipKirkbride